# i want to do seetings for proxy in android emulator

Tags: android

1. > adb shell
2. # sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
3. sqlite> INSERT INTO system VALUES(99,’http_proxy', 'proxy:port');
4. sqlite>.exit

but it is solution for temporary....i want to do perment ...when i restart my Emulator than i must set again all settings..so whats solution of this problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a command line option `-http-proxy` when starting the emulator

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html